# Why does this function return None, but when I type out what it does manually, it returns something different?

Tags: python, function

Here is my code:

```
dict = {
"a":"1"
}

def dict_find(x):
    print dict.get('x')

dict_find('a')
print dict.get('a')
```

The output for `dict_find('a')` is `None`, but the output for manually writing it out as `print dict.get('a')` is `1`.

Comment: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html

Comment: `dict_find` looks for the key 'x' no matter what parameter you pass to it. It should be `print dict.get(x)` instead of `print dict.get('x')`.

Answer (score 5):

That is because your function does not use the variable `x` but the string `'x'`, which is not a key of dict.

Additionally, your function has no return statement. A function without return statement always return `None`.

Also, you should not use `dict` as a variable name, since it is a built-in type.

```
dic = {"a":"1"}
def dict_find(x):
    return dic.get(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your function `dict_find` you use the string `'x'` as a parameter for `dict.get` instead of the the submitted argument `x` and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) returns `None` for a key that is not part of the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `'x'`, not `x` (note the quotes).

A better version of the code might be:

```
dict = {
    'a': 1,
}

def dict_find(key):
    return dict.get(key)

print dict_find('a')
print dict.get('a')
```